# Alpha semi transparent issue

Tags: transparency

I downloaded a model of the game FF7re,after adding alpha texture,the part supposed to be transparent can still be seen.

[image: The left picture]

Also,the normal tangent creates weird effect(the right picture).I am new to blender and I guess it might be some error settings because I heard it doesn't go wrong in maya.

Here is the packed blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XWDHbqCjwzVMJ0q8tFMpTxiwGTRac7p2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems light gets stronger after it pass the alpha part of the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

I just request access to your file,
but I think the issue is from material setting
you should switch the Blend Mode to Alpha Clip

[image]

Comment: I find that option but it doesn't help.

Comment: can you please give me access to the file,? (i requested yesterday already)
maybe i can solve the issue

Comment: I already put the google link in the description - -

Comment: yeah i know, but its permission required and i already requested.

Comment: Oh I am sorry , I wanted to set it accessable for everyone. Here is the new link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XWDHbqCjwzVMJ0q8tFMpTxiwGTRac7p2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry i can't solve the issue
but i think its likely common problem in cycles engine
its caused by overlapping or intersecting the geometry which caused the black artifact
but its fine in eevee with alpha clip setting
see image below

https://prnt.sc/ti8a3y

i've follow this question hope will be solved soon